# bind and unbind within a even listener block

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.arrow').click(function(e){
    run();
    $(this).off(e); // unbind 
    setTimeout(function(){ /*rebind back*/ }, 700);   
});
```

How to rebind back the click event within the block itself? I only manage to off() the click but unable to rebind back.

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: @ArunPJohny because the if user click too fast, fadeIn within my run function will ruined. so I kinda want to set 700 ms to unbind the click event to prevent double clicked / too fast clicking.

Comment: or you could debouce the event

Comment: @mkoryak any code related to that? how to apply to my case?

Comment: @EltonJamie There's lots of that information [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=debounce%20javascript).

Answer (score 1):

name your callback:

```
$('.arrow').on("click", function cb(e){
    run();
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.off(e); // unbind 
    setTimeout(function(){ $this.on("click", cb); }, 700);   
});
```

or debounce it, like i said. choose your favorite debounce impl, here is [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce):

```
$('.arrow').on("click", _.debounce(run, 700));
```

Comment: yeah, thats why i decided to answer a few questions tonight ;)

Comment: Nice :). I did the same to get to 2k this weekend. Then an OP unaccepted my answer :(. Then I got another upvote randomly.

Comment: @EltonJamie you can get a debounce impl anywhere you want. you can write one yourself. I happen to have one you can borrow from here: https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead/blob/master/jquery.floatThead._.js#L38

Comment: @EltonJamie if you're tied down to just jquery in your app, you're kind of limiting yourself.

Comment: @MillieSmith it's the requirement of the project :(

Comment: underscore is 5.7k of awesome. im sure your boss wont mind the productivity